# Limitations of jboss AS 7 over glassfish

Tags: java, jsp, ejb, jboss7.x, glassfish-4

We have a 10 years old java application, right now we are using jboss 7 server. we find it too slow. So for migrating to glassfish, kindly suggest me the lilitations of jboss AS 7 over glassfish 4...

Comment: Whilst this is off topic as it’s purely opinionated, we recently migrated **to** JBoss :)

Comment: jboss enterprise version or community version?

Comment: please do give some difference between jboss EAP and community versions. I am completely new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, JBoss > Glassfish or Tomcat.

You could try fine tuning your enterprise application or better still, run a benchmark between JBoss and Glassfish, check the performance between the two in a production environment.

Am sure the test scenario would give you enough insight into performance tuning/upgrading your application to a version closer to JavaEE 6/7+ and a JBoss supported version.

Comment: thanks...So you are meant to say instead of migrating we could go for fine tuning first.

Comment: Suganya, what I meant to say is you can deploy your App on the latest version of JBoss Wildfly and Glassfish, test/benchmark it for performance, see which part is taking unusually long to execute, ie, database access or "in-between" requests.

Comment: Another *fact* - JBoss Wildfly uses up/requires more memory than Glassfish at the most basic configuration - basically means, no Apps deployed. Like I said, your question could have several answers and not sure SFO allows such 'broad based' discussions. A forum would be a better platform imho.

Comment: Thanks a lot Venkat ji... :)

Comment: And glassfish is full of bugs... i wouldn't even consider it for production. Seems oracle gave it a cold shoulder, and inspired such other servers as `payara.fish` which is based on glassfish but far more stable for production